# Avoiding exceptions vs handling exceptions in Java

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, coding-style

I am implementing a DELETE rest endpoint in spring boot, I am not sure which approach is better between below 2 approaches:

1. First checking if the record with given Id exists in the database and then delete it safely.
2. Directly calling delete on spring data repository and catching EmptyResultDataAccessException thrown by spring data to return 404 response.

I like the first one as the code is more readable and does not involve controlling flow using exceptions. However, it involves an additional call to db and potential race condition.

Why would you prefer the first or the second approach?

Comment: why not write your code in such a way that this scenario can't occur?

Comment: I'd prefer the first, and a way to avoid the race condition would be to place the check and the delete inside a transaction

Comment: What @Stultuske says is 100% correct, why allow deletion of something that can not exist? That id should not be available in the first place

Comment: Its a rest resource and an user can enter any id in the URL. curl -X DELETE \
  'http://localhost:8080/resource/{id}' \. what if there is no resource with given id

Comment: @varun One way would be to hold all the available IDs in memory, a `Set` for example. And with every database update you also update that set, you can then check if a given ID exist when a DELETE is requested, this approach may be a problem if you're working with a large amount of data though

Comment: @lino even if the data is not huge this is still a problem as I would not like to trust a set in memory is source of truth and what happens when say I deploy my application again or I deploy app as multi instance with a load balancer.

Comment: @Lino What you say is not in accordance with REST conventions. A DELETE on a resource which is not present (anymore) can always occur and should not even result in an error, but an HTTP 200 or 204.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster I did not say that one must throw an exception, it would be just an easy way to check if it exist. If yes -> delete it -> return 200. If no -> return 200 directly

Answer (score 1):

If you annotate the service method with @Transactional there will be no race condition and it's fine to check for existence first (with a small performance overhead).

On the other hand I always like the simplicity of attempting the deletion and catching the exception, the assumption being that deleting a non-existent resource is exceptional.

Note also that in REST a DELETE on a non-existing resource should normally return a succesful HTTP status code 200 (OK) or 204 (NO_CONTENT).

```
@Transactional
public Response deleteAfterChecking(Thing thing) {
    if (!repository.exists(thing)) {                        
        repository.delete(thing);            
    }
    return Response.NO_CONTENT;
}

public Response deleteHandlingException(Thing thing) {
    try {               
        repository.delete(thing);            
    }
    catch (NotFoundException e) {
        // do nothing
    }
    return Response.NO_CONTENT;
}
```

Comment: I asked this question more as a discussion of pros and cons as both the options are viable and none of hem is particularly insane thing to do. I dont feel the need of a service layer because this is a very small and simple application. Even though I introduce a service layer still the original question remains to check and act or to catch exception and wrapping into another exception is different question all together.

Comment: You mentioned about the simplicity of calling delete and catching exception but I dont agree to this as now my function does not have single exit which is more difficult to test

Comment: Your method won't have a single flow either way. The check for existance can fail or succeed, requiring a different flow.

Comment: `204` is `No Content`, not `Deleted`. The IANA registry (https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) does not have a response code whose description is `Deleted`. That said, a `204 No Content` is a reasonable code to return in response to a DELETE request.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @EricStein I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

*The first option is better* conventions-wise and will be more readable, but not performance-wise on big amounts of data as you will need two calls. Indeed, you should not need to catch an EmptyResultDataAccessException at any point.

You should nonetheless think about your code conception. How can the ID of a potentially non-persisted object be passed ? Is it necessary ? Without your code, I can't judge, but I believe you should consider this.

Comment: its a rest resource so a user can pass any id in the URL. curl -X DELETE \
  'http://localhost:8080/resource/{id}' \. Also can you explain your view when you quoted you should not need to catch an EmptyResultDataAccessException at any point.

Comment: @varun It's more of a convention and less of a reality, but it is a preventable exception, and it is usually better to prevent an exception than catching it. Thanks for your explanation. I suppose there is no workaround to the Rest resource and the user must be able to pass any ID ? Otherwise I'd go so far as to listing the existing IDs and letting the user pick any of that list, but that might not be an option.
Anyway, if your data volumetry is high enough for you to be worried about performance issues, you can consider the second option ; otherwise, the first one should be your go-to.